# App shows nothing after implementation of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This is simple widget which is showing set of bitmaps taken from external storage. It basically works but makes monit that App makes too much work on its main thread, so i put things in AsyncTask, but then widget remains empty, no bitmaps are loaded. Here is code which works:

```
public class PhotosLoader /*extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,ArrayList<Bitmap>> */ {
    private Context mContext;
    private RemoteViews views;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> images;

    public PhotosLoader (Context context, RemoteViews views){
        mContext = context;
        this.views = views;
    }

    public ArrayList<Bitmap> LoadPhotos() {
        PhotosReader PR = new PhotosReader();
        images = PR.getPhotosArray(mContext);
        PhotosModifier PM = new PhotosModifier();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = PM.getResizedPhotosBitmap(images);
        return bitmaps;
    }

    public void inflatePhotos(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps){
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmaps.get(0));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, bitmaps.get(1));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView3, bitmaps.get(2));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView4, bitmaps.get(3));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView5, bitmaps.get(4));
    }
}
```

onUpdate method:

```
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            PhotosLoader PL = new PhotosLoader(context, views);
            ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = PL.LoadPhotos();
            PL.inflatePhotos(bitmaps);
        }
    }
```

And there is code which doesn't:

```
public class PhotosLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,ArrayList<Bitmap>> {
    private Context mContext;
    private RemoteViews views;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> images;

    public PhotosLoader (Context context, RemoteViews views){
        mContext = context;
        this.views = views;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        PhotosReader PR = new PhotosReader();
        images = PR.getPhotosArray(mContext);
        PhotosModifier PM = new PhotosModifier();
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = PM.getResizedPhotosBitmap(images);
        return bitmaps;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmaps);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, bitmaps.get(0));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView2, bitmaps.get(1));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView3, bitmaps.get(2));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView4, bitmaps.get(3));
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView5, bitmaps.get(4));
    }
}
```

onUpdate:

```
   @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            new PhotosLoader(context, views).execute();
            Log.d("Main","onUpdate");
        }
    }
```

those are only code changes in project, my first implementation of AsyncTask, so Idk what I could did wrong, looks so simple

Comment: `PL.exec(params...)` ? Also `doInBackground()` has void params..Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Any log warnings or errors? Is onPostExecute actually executed (if you add a `Log.d` there, does it print?) ?

Comment: No warnings, everything works fine in logcat, onPost also is being called

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan could you explain more? I have read this and few other threads here on site but still I don't see problem...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the fact that you're trying to update the RemoteView object *after* you've returned it from the `onUpdate` method. You should return it already constructed and filled in with the required data.

Maybe try a different approach than passing Bitmaps and set `Uri`s to your images on the `ImageView`s instead?

Edit: actually, one more problem might be that you don't actually update the widget anywhere :D You create the RemoteView then just drop it. Are you calling `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget` ?

Comment: Widget is updating itself by making query from external storage for newest photos in class that I didn't show here because it was unnecessary for this particular problem. I know there are a lot of not so good solutions in my code but this is my very first app and I made this creature. Now I want to improve it on every possible way. PS pozdrawiam z PL :)